# How to enumerate Object?

Tags: c#

I am trying to enumerate Object which is actually enumerable, but the type is stored in Type variable

```
public Type MyListType { get; set; }
public Object MyList { get; set; }
...
foreach (var item in Convert.ChangeType(MyList, MyListType))
{
...
}
```

This obviously gives an error because ChangeType still returns Object. How can I cast MyList into enumerable type, particularly of MyListType?

Update:

To be more clear, Object is `BindingList<T>` type, where T is residing in MyListType.

Comment: What you mean by "enumerate Object"? Do you like do navigate through its properties (like javascript do) or it is an IEnumerable object? The result for the following check is `true`? `MyList is IEnumerable`

Comment: It is an IEnumerable objects, more particularly BindingList.

Comment: So why not do `foreach(SomeType item in (BindingList)MyList)`?

Comment: @Pablo Is it *always* a `BindingList`, or is it a `BindingList` in just one test case?  If it's *always* a `BindingList` why is the variable not of type `BindingList`?

Comment: If it is a BindingList, @jon-skeet answer is perfect for you.

Comment: It's `BindingList<T>` one, sorry for not being clear. `T` is unknown in the code that I am dealing with. I only have T as MyListType.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well if it's *actually* enumerable, presumably it implements `IEnumerable`... so you can just use:

```
foreach (object item in (IEnumerable) MyList)
{
    ...
}
```

You're not going to have a better compile-time type for `item` than `object` anyway...

Comment: Unless it's an evil type that has a suitable `GetEnumerator` method without actually implementing `IEnumerable`.

Comment: @Servy: Ooh, good point. It depends on what the OP means by "actually enumeratable" I guess.

Comment: the object is BindingList type. This option gives me an error, because IEnumerable requires T type, which I have only in `MyListType`.

Comment: There is a non generic [`IEnumerable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerable(v=vs.110).aspx), it shouldn't require a T.

Comment: @Pablo: As Yuval says, I'm referring to `System.Collections.IEnumerable` - make sure you've got a using directive for `System.Collections`, not just `System.Collections.Generic`.

Comment: "Using the generic type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>' requires 1 type arguments". Not sure how to force generic one.

Comment: @Pablo Did you incude `using System.Collections;` at the top of your file?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain: after including System.Collections the error disappeared, let me check the result though...

Answer (score 0):

If the type actually implements `IEnumerable` you can simply cast it to that:

```
foreach (object item in (IEnumerable) MyList)
{
    //...
}
```

If the type has a `GetEnumerator` method that meets the criteria for `foreach`, making it enumerable in the conceptual sense, but without actually implementing `IEnumerable`, then you'll need to use `dynamic` to defer the problem to the runtime, at which point it will be able to figure out which method to call dynamically.

```
foreach (object item in (dynamic) MyList)
{
    //...
}
```

(Note that while this is an interesting academic exercise, I *really* hope you don't actually have such an object in actual production code; you almost certainly shouldn't be using this solution outside of experimentation.)